# Using ROLES in jhipster?

Tags: spring-security, jhipster, user-roles

I tried to add and change roles in jhipster. First I just tried to change one use case's role to admin from user. Then I tested it and user can add employee even if the roles is ROLE_ADMIN so it didn't change anything.

I added new role as well, called MANAGER. I edited AuthoritiesConstants.java and added new role to  JHI_AUTHORITY-table. Should I do something else or is this enough to get this working?

```
state('employee.new', {
            parent: 'employee',
            url: '/new',
            data: {
                roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
            },
            onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
                $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'scripts/app/entities/employee/employee-dialog.html',
                    controller: 'EmployeeDialogController',
                    size: 'lg',
                    resolve: {
                        entity: function () {
                            return {nameFirst: null, nameLast: null, taxNumber: null, isFinnish: null, finnishSOTU: null, valtticard: null, birthDate: null, isContactPerson: null, isTiedonantaja: null, cOTARKENNE: null, id: null};
                        }
                    }
                }).result.then(function(result) {
                    $state.go('employee', null, { reload: true });
                }, function() {
                    $state.go('employee');
                })
            }]
        })
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Role assigned to state does not restrict access to page when logged in with a different role.

Answer (score 13):

**Edit the following 6 files to include/exclude code specified in blocks to add/remove a role(ROLE_MANAGER as an example)**

1. AuthoritiesConstants.java (constant to be used in java)

   > public static final String MANAGER = "ROLE_MANAGER";
2. src/main/resources/config/liquibase/authorities.csv (proper liquidbase update)

   > ROLE_MANAGER
3. src/main/resources/config/liquibase/users.csv (add username: manager with password: user)

   > 5;manager;$2a$10$VEjxo0jq2YG9Rbk2HmX9S.k1uZBGYUHdUcid3g/vfiEl7lwWgOH/K;Manager;Manager;manager@localhost;true;en;system
4. src/main/resources/config/liquibase/users_authorities.csv (another proper liquidbase update)

   > 5;ROLE_MANAGER
5. src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management.controller.js (for role to be available in JavaScript)

   > $scope.authorities = ["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"**, "ROLE_MANAGER"**];
6. src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-dialog.controller.js (for role to be available in JavaScript)

   > $scope.authorities = ["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"**, "ROLE_MANAGER"**];

Restart the server once everything is in place and double check JHI_AUTHORITY and JHI_USER_AUTHORITY tables after application launch for a new ROLE_MANAGER to be there. Login into system with username: 'manager' and password: 'user'.

Comment: UnexpectedLiquibaseException: CSV Line 5 has only 9 columns, the header has 10. I corrected as follows. Edited users.csv: 
5;manager;$2a$10$VEjxo0jq2YG9Rbk2HmX9S.k1uZBGYUHdUcid3g/vfiEl7lwWgOH/K;Manager;Manager;manager@localhost;true;en;system;system

Comment: I had to drop the database and re-run the server to make it work. As otherwise liquidbase was complaining about checksum validation error;
`Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: Validation Failed`

Comment: src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management.controller.js is not available anymore

Answer (score 1):

You must insert new role into JHI_AUTHORITY table then grant this role to some users in JHI_USER_AUTHORITY table. This means updating authorities.csv and users_authorities.csv file if you re-create your database (e.g. if you use H2).

On client-side, just add new role to roles property of your state definitions.

Comment: But if I add roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN'], does it mean that ROLE_USER can't go to employee.new? In my case it didn't work that way, User could add a new employee as well, so something is missing now? I am using mySQL and I added new role by hand to db.

Comment: Roles are independent from each others, a user having ROLE_ADMIN does not necessary have ROLE_USER, it's up to you to grant both roles to same user. In your state you can set roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'] if you want to authorize user with any of these 2 roles to access this state.

Comment: I mean that I have roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN'], but still user with role ROLE_USER could go and add new employees, the roles are not working in my case.

Comment: Are you sure that your API returns correct roles, have you checked in browser's console?

Comment: roles: ["ROLE_USER"]
0: "ROLE_USER" This in response when log in.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an easiest way:

1. Disable liquibase from .gradle file (in my case App>gradle>profile_dev.gradle) by changing the following:

   def profiles = 'dev,no-liquibase'
   //if (project.hasProperty('no-liquibase')) {
   //    profiles += ',no-liquibase'
   //}
2. Now change in src/main/webapp/scripts/app/admin/user-management/user-management.controller.js to add your role.

   $scope.authorities = ["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN", "YOUR_ROLE"];
3. And src/main/webapp/scripts/app/admin/user-management/user-management-dialog.controller.js

   $scope.authorities = ["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN", "YOUR_ROLE"];
4. Finally add "YOUR_ROLE" in "name" column of "jhi_authority" table in database and save. Now restart application and you will able to create user with your newly created role.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a leaf out of @Constantin Zagorsky here are the steps that work.

1. `AuthoritiesConstants.java` (constant to be used in java)

> public static final String MANAGER = "ROLE_MANAGER";

2.`src/main/resources/config/liquibase/authorities.csv` (proper liquibase update) [**This will not run. But important to keep in sync with DB**]

> ROLE_MANAGER

3. ***Update DB*** [Important because liquibase will not pick up changes made in authorities,csv in step 2]

   `insert into jhi_authority values ('ROLE_MANAGER');`
4. `src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management.controller.js`(for role to be available in JavaScript)

> $scope.authorities = ["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_MANAGER"];

5. `src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-dialog.controller.js`(for role to be available in JavaScript)

> $scope.authorities = ["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_MANAGER"];

6. Modify  public User createUser(ManagedUserVM managedUserVM) method in UserService.java **(Very Important)**. ***Modify default password generation logic***

> // comment default password generation. In my case I made the default
>   //user as same as userid
>
> //String encryptedPassword =
>   passwordEncoder.encode(RandomUtil.generatePassword());
>           String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(managedUserVM.getLogin());

7. Log into application as Admin
8. Add new user with a new role. Default password would be same as username.

Answer (score 0):

After above instruction I got:

```
ERROR [...]f.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase  : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: Validation Failed:
[...]
```

To avoid that, run

```
./mvnw liquibase:clearCheckSums
```

User with new role, has no access to account settings, so you have to add new roles to

```
/src/main/webapp/app/account/password/password.state.js
/src/main/webapp/app/account/sessions/sessions.state.js
/src/main/webapp/app/account/settings/settings.state.js
```

Complete instruction:
https://codefitter2.blogspot.com/2016/11/how-to-create-new-role-in-jhipster.html

Answer (score 0):

In JHipster 6, the csv file is named `authority.csv`. So change this file along the `AuthoritiesConstants.java` as described in previous posts.

[image]